# iphone development: verify the certificate information from a https url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, security

When a user connects to a "https url", for example: "https://encrypted.google.com", using a web browser (Safari, Chrome, ...), then the user can get information about the certificate related to a such "https url"; that is, in the case of connecting to the url "https://encrypted.google.com", it is possible to verify the following certificate information:

1. Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
2. *.google.com Issued by: Google Internet Authority. The expiration date of the certificate. whether the certificate is valid or no
3. More details about the certificate like signature algorithm, public key info, fingerprints, etc.

So, the question is: "What are the proper Objective C function calls in order to get the aforementioned information (or at least to know if the certificate is valid)?"

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9):

Certificate information can be obtained using NSURLConnection delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

That is:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
BOOL  result = [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> Result:%s", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (result == YES) ? "YES" : "NO");
return result;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection      didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSArray *trustedHosts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"encrypted.google.com"];
BOOL isAuthMethodServerTrust = [challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> Result:%s", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (isAuthMethodServerTrust == YES) ? "YES" : "NO");
if (isAuthMethodServerTrust)
{
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
    {
        NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        NSURLCredential* urlCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> Url credential", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);         
        [challenge.sender useCredential:urlCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        //Code to verify certificate info
        SecTrustRef trustRef = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
        CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef); 

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, i);
            CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
            CFDataRef certData = SecCertificateCopyData(certRef);
            NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> Certificate summary:%@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (NSString*) certSummary);
            NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> Certificate data:%@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (NSString*) certData);
            CFRelease(certData);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This code gives you the following information related to "https://encrypted.google.com":
In the "certSummary" NSString the issuer of the certificate.
In the "certData" data of the certificate. The problem is that at present I do not know how extract information from a such data (expiration date, public key, ...), so any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code!

I'm currently trying to do fingerprint validation on server certificates with HTTPS connections using UIWebView controller.

I'm going to use OpenSSL functions to do the rest of the validation. Once you have the certData, you can use OpenSSL to parse the X509 certificate and perform the rest of the validation that you need.

Getting OpenSSL into your projects might be a bit troublesome.

Comment: Although this an quite old post, @Genar did you ever figured out how to parse more detailed information from the certificate data you loaded? In my test 'certSummary' only prints me the URL of the website in test.