# Using NSURLConnection for SSL with a self signed certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, https, nsurlconnection

I'm using `NSURLConnection` for HTTPS (SSL) communication with my service.

I'm trying to block "man in the middle" scenario (SSL proxies that steal data),
In a self signed server SSL authentication.

StackOverflow is full with solutions to allow ANY certificate,
which is not good enough. Some of these solutions also test host url, but again, this is not good enough because faking DNS address is very easy.

As I recall, openSSL allows you to use a CA file to identify the server.
Do you know how to do that with `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402442/iphone-development-verify-the-certificate-information-from-a-https-url