# Certificate Expiry Date check

Tags: ssl-certificate

How can i check the expiry date of certificate inside connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate method when we have HTTPS connection with server ?

Regards,
Chandrika

Answer (score 0):

Bhat - Isnt it complete answer of your question:
[verify the certificate information from a https url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496278/502950)

It wasnt accepted yet, but it is what you want I think. And you can use it a start point.